# What do I have here

Tags: maintenance

completely blank frame except J62460170 stamped on the underside[image]

Comment: Basically, it is a BMX bike. It is really hard to identify them unless there are any prominent features on the frame. And I am afraid, this one has nothing. Even if you have learned that this frame was made by X at city Y in country Z, what would that information give you?

Comment: BTW serial numbers are completely useless if you don't already know the brand, and even then they're not a lot of help.

Comment: Please clarifty - are the cranks painted, anodised, or something else ?   Also, are the rims the same as the cranks ?   The front rim looks purple in the photo, and the back doesn't show up very well.

Comment: A photo from the other side would be useful. Or just read answers to this one: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: A BMX bike without those awful Ashtabula cranks. What a unicorn!

Answer (score 1):

All I can see is a relatively recent BMX - ie under 20 years old.

The anodised cranks could be older than the bike - there were anodised parts fads in the 90s, but they came and went repeatedly since then.

That tiny chainring suggests its not a race bike or a track bike.  Instead its for going slow.  But it has no pegs or grind plates or any wear from tricks.  I also see no evidence of a Potts mod to allow the bars to rotate 360 degrees.

In fact, I see a bike with brake studs under the seat stays, but no brakes.  Someone has actively removed the brakes for some absurd reason.  There are empty cable mounts under the top tube too.

Given there appears to be no provision for a front brake at all, I think this is a cheap BSO kid's bike from a big box store.

If you want to ride it, please fit two brakes and make sure they work.  Function is critical!

Other than that, the content of the picture looks eminently rideable, and you should totally ride it.

Comment: Okay, fact check time... The lack of front brake, pegs or gyro and overall geometry suggest that it's a race bike. The cranks look like steel Bullseye (old and very expensive) or knockoffs, not anodized but painted. The rear cog is extremely small, so the overall ratio is not that low but still less than what you would expect from race BMX. There is no option for mounting front brake, but for racing on closed circuit with banked turns there's no need for one either.

Comment: @ojs Fair enough.  Feel free to add another answer.

Comment: Yes, definitely not a cheap BSO. And it appears that there is a coaster brake arm attached to the drive side chainstay, so it does have a brake. Two would be safer, but a lot of BMX bikes are ridden with just one.

Comment: I don't see a brake arm there and never heard about brake arm on drive side anyway.

Comment: @Andrew I see no reaction arm for a coaster brake on either chainstay - Could it be the dropout you're seeing ?

Comment: You’re right. It’s the corner of the dropout.